# Navbar bootstrap 2.3 to 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I decided to upgrade a website, from bootstrap 2.3 to bootstrap 3, but it has some small problems, the main one is with the navbar, which was working perfectly now adds the unordered list in vertical instead of horizontal, at the same time there is one empty border in the left right.

the current code for the css is the following, sorry if there is something wrong I'm jus a noob in website programming:

```
.navbar ul.nav { padding-top: 15px; }
.navbar ul.nav li a {
     color:#333; 
     position:relative;
      display:inline; 
      font-weight: 800; text-decoration:none; font-size:12px; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:none; display:inline;
   -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
   -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
   -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
   -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
   transition: all 300ms linear;

   background: none;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none; box-shadow:none;
}

.navbar ul.nav li.active a,
.navbar ul.nav li.active a:hover,
.navbar ul.nav li a:hover,
.navbar ul.nav li a.selected { color:/*#FFCC00*/#E9322D; text-decoration: none;
   background: none;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none; box-shadow:none;
}
```

Comment: Any way we can see the HTML? The issue may not be CSS related.

Comment: Try http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps.

http://code.divshot.com/bootstrap3_upgrader/

Its a bootstrap upgrading tool. Hope this helps........